# Controlando entradas e saídas extras no Arduino Uno e Mega 2560 via software

Tags: arduino

Durante o desenvolvimento de um projeto em Arduino, precisei de mais terminais (entradas e saídas) digitais, além das indicadas na placa.

É possível controlar, via software, mais terminais (pinos) digitais extras nas placas Arduino Uno e Arduino Mega 2560, sem a necessidade de soldar algo na placa, usar shields, ou componentes externos?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

É possível utilizar mais terminais digitais (pinos) nas placas Arduino Uno e Mega 2560, além dos indicados na placa, transformando as entradas analógicas (A0, A1, A2...) em entradas ou saídas digitais.

Para o Arduino Uno, basta utilizar os seguintes números para cada um dos terminais analógicos:

- A0: 14
- A1: 15
- A2: 16
- A3: 17
- A4: 18
- A5: 19

Por exemplo, o código:

```
pinMode(14, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(14, 1);
pinMode(15, INPUT);
```

Faz com que o terminal A0 se transforme em uma saída digital, e escreve 1 nele. Por fim,também transforma o terminal A1 em uma entrada digital (para ser utilizada com digitalRead).

Já para o Arduino Mega 2560:

- A0: 54
- A1: 55
- A2: 56
- A3: 57
- A4: 58
- A5: 59
- A6: 60
- A7: 61
- A8: 62
- A9: 63
- A10: 64
- A11: 65
- A12: 66
- A13: 67
- A14: 68
- A15: 69

Assim, no Arduino Mega 2560, o código:

```
pinMode(69, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(69, 1);
pinMode(54, INPUT);
```

Faz com que o terminal A15 se transforme em uma saída digital, e escreve 1 nele. Por fim, também transforma o terminal A0 em uma entrada digital (para ser utilizada com digitalRead).

É possível, também, utilizar os próprios nomes dos terminais analógicos em vez dos números, caso se deseje. Assim, tanto no Arduino Uno como no Arduino Mega 2560, o código:

```
pinMode(A0, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(A0, 1);
pinMode(A1, INPUT);
```

Faz com que o terminal A0 se transforme em uma saída digital, e escreve 1 nele. Por fim, também transforma o terminal A1 em uma entrada digital (para ser utilizada com digitalRead), conforme observado por @carlos-delfino.

Espero que ajude quem estiver precisando de mais entradas ou saídas extras nos projetos!

Answer (score 6):

Para uso das portas Analógicas como portas digitais, basta usar seus nomes como  referencia da mesma forma que utilizando como analógicas, ou seja, nos comandos pinMode(), digitalRead() e digitalWrite() use da seguinte forma:

```
void setup(){
   pinMode(A1,OUTPUT);
   pinMode(A3,INPUT);
}
void loop(){
.....
leitura = digitalRead(A1);
.....
digitalWrite(A3, LOW);
.....
}
```

Comment: Bem lembrado! Vou acrescentar essa informação à resposta.