# Dúvida pinagem Atmega328

Tags: arduino

Eu estou utilizando o Atmega328 em meu projeto, e eu estava vendo o datasheet e estou em duvida se os pinos 22, 23, e 24 do atmega328 funciona como Analógio e **Digital**, estou em duvida. Alguem poderia me ajudar ?

Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Os pinos analógicos do Atmega328 vão do 23 ao 28. O pino 22 é GND.

Note que embora a imagem mencione o Atmega168, o mesmo serve para o Atmega328. Veja aqui: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/PinMapping168

[image: Mapeamento de Pinos Atmega168/328 para o Arduino]

Os pinos analógicos podem ser utilizados como pinos digitais. Veja essa resposta para o Arduino UNO (que usa um Atmega328): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/13872/3084

Comment: Legal, Obrigado amigo pela resposta, me ajudou bastante.

Comment: Me surgiu outra duvida, eu vi no datasheet que tem 2 VCC e 3 GND. Eu preciso ligar todos ou eu posso ligar apenas 1 VCC e 1 GND ?

Comment: Olha, eu não vou te dar certeza nessa resposta, mas posso te dar uma sugestão: Verifique alguns esquemáticos de Arduino na Internet com o Atmega328. Creio que o AVCC (pino 20) é ligado em paralelo com o VCC (7). Se vc tiver uma placa de arduino Uno ou Duemilinove você também pode verificar como é feito. Enfim, projetos do Arduino são seus amigos e por serem open-source fica bem tranquilo verificar.

Comment: Só mais uma duvida, estou utilizando a serial do atmega328 para controlar um módulo bluetooth, mas eu gostaria de utilizar a mesma saida serial para se comunicar com outro atmega328, como eu posso fazer ?

Comment: Poste isso como uma pergunta para que eu possa responder você. Creio que isso pode ser de interesse de outras pessoas. Poste o código onde você tenta fazer essa comunicação.

Comment: Pronto, segue a nova pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/101417/multipla-comunica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-serial