# Multipla comunicação serial com Atmega328

Tags: arduino

Estou utilizando a serial do atmega328 para controlar um módulo bluetooth, mas eu gostaria de utilizar a mesma saida serial para se comunicar com outro atmega328, como eu posso fazer ?

Comment: Você consegue fazer alguma comunicacao serial?

Comment: Há duas alternativas: usar um chaveamento com transistores ou com portas lógicas. Isso seria uma "gambiarra", mas é possível de ser feito. Você precisaria gastar mais uma porta digital para "ativar" e "desativar" este chaveamento. Também podes usar a biblioteca SoftwareSerial e utilizar algumas portas digitais do Arduino, como se fossem portas seriais (isto é emulado via software, como o próprio nome da biblioteca já diz). Infelizmente esta pergunta está fechada e não consigo colocar mais detalhes sobre essas coisas em um campo de comentários.

Answer (score 0):

O Atmega328 possui apenas 2 pinos para comunicação serial, são eles: 2,3. Numa placa Arduino (como a Uno e Duemilinove), esses pinos são mapeados para os pinos 0,1.

A comunicação serial via cabo USB numa placa Arduino também utiliza esses pinos. Isso significa que você não consegue fazer um programa que se comunique via Serial com um computador e, ao mesmo tempo, com outro dispositivo qualquer.

O mesmo é válido para um dispositivo bluetooth que se comunica via serial. Como você está utilizando o pino 0,1 do Arduino para conectar o dispositivo bluetooth, então você não consegue conectar nenhum outro dispostivo com o Atmega328 via serial.

As suas alternativas são:

1. Utilizar um ATmega1280 (micro-controlador da placa Arduino Mega). Esse chip tem 4 saídas seriais. Assim, você pode ligar o bluetooth numa dessas saídas e o restante você pode utilizar para conectar outros dispositivos seriais;
2. Utilizar o dispositivo bluetooth via serial e fazer a comunicação de um Arduino com outro via Ethernet;
3. Encontrar um dispostivio bluetooth que se comunique via protocolo I2C. Não posso afirmar que exista.
4. Fazer um Arduino se comunicar com outro via protocolo I2C. Essa parece bem interessante e tem até uma documentação: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterWriter

Comment: Entendi, mas se o arduino uno consegue receber os dados de uma USB e ter um modulo bluetooth espetado no arduino uno, então o atmega328 consegue gerenciar a serial para uso duplo. Certo ? Eu quero gravar o Atmega no Arduino Uno, depois tirar ele e espetar em uma protoboard, assim não teria a USB da placa oiginal e assim eu conseguiria fazer oque desejo. Entendeu minha déuvida ?

Comment: Sim entendi. Veja que, embora você ligue um cabo USB, a comunicação é serial. No Arudino existe um chip que converte USB-Serial. A serial da USB está ligada em paralelo com o pino 0,1 de uma placa Arduino. Portanto, é a mesma serial e não dá pra utilizar pra dois propósitos distintos.

Comment: Eu entendi, Mas faz de conta que não exista a USB na placa arduino, então eu poderia ligar outra coisa em paralelo, concorda ?

Comment: Sim. Mas vc quer ligar em paralelo e conseguir controlar duas coisas distintas de maneira distinta? Se o dado que vai via bluetooth também vai para o outro Arduindo, então tudo bem, pode ser que funcione. Mas se vc quiser comportamentos distintos, então com uma serial só não tem como.

Comment: Vou ter dar um exemplo: Fiz um dispositivo que se conecta com uma balança analítica. O Arduino está conectado somente nessa balanca. Se eu quiser conectar um computador ao mesmo tempo, enviando outras informações, então preciso de um micro-controlador que me dê mais saídas seriais. O mesmo vale para quando você usar o Atmega328 sem ser numa placa Arduino.